# In which order is an if statement evaluated in Python

Tags: python

If you have an if statement where several variables or functions are evaluated, in which order are they evaluated?

```
if foo > 5 or bar > 6:
    print 'foobar'
```

In this specific case, will foo be evaluated against the five and then bar against the 6 (left to right) or will it be evaluated right to left? I am assuming that a `or` and `and` is evaluated in the same order.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the order of evaluation of an `if` statement, but with the order of evaluation of an `or` expression. You get the exact same rules for `x = (foo > 5 or bar > 6)`, or, for that matter, just `foo > 5 or bar > 6` as a statement on its own.

Comment: Try playing around and see what happens. Like what would be the outcome of this ;) `if True or False and False and False or False:`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The left clause will be evaluated first, and then the right one only if the first one is `False`.

This is why you can do stuff like:

```
if not person or person.name == 'Bob':
    print "You have to select a person and it can't be Bob"
```

Without it breaking.

Conversely, with an `and` clause, the right clause will only be evaluated if the first one is `True`:

```
if person and person.name:
   # ...
```

Otherwise an exception would be thrown when `person` is `None`.

Comment: This is such an insightful answer. Does anyone know a collective reference containing such kind of trap-evading tips?

Answer (score 13):

To expand Blender's explanation a bit further, the `or` operator has something else built-in:

```
<expression A> or <expression B>
```

This will evaluate `expression A` first; if it evaluates to `True` then `expression A` is returned by the operator. So `5 or <something>` will return `5` as `5` evaluates to `True`.

If `expression A` evaluates to `False`, `expression B` is returned. So `0 or 5` will return `5` because `0` evaluates to `False`.

Of course you can chain this as much as you want:

```
<expr 1> or <expr 2> or <expr 3> or ... or <expr n>
```

In general, `or` will return the *first* expression which evaluates to `True`, but keep its original value. If there is no expression that evaluates to `True`, it will simply return the last expression (which evaluates to `False`).

The `and` operator works in a similar but inversed way. It will return the *first* expression which does evaluate to `False`, but keep its original value. If there is no expression that evaluates to `False`, it will simply return the last expression (which will evaluate to `True`).

As an example, both `0 and 5` and `5 and 0` will return `0` because `0` evaluates to `False`, but `2 and 3` will return `3` because `3` is the last expression and everything evaluates to `True`.

In any way (to come back to the question): All expressions are evaluated from left to right, and if a rule from above allows it, further expressions will not be touched.

Answer (score 11):

It will be evaluated left to right.

```
>>> def a():
...     print 'a'
...     return False
... 
>>> def b():
...     print 'b'
...     return False
... 
>>> print a() or b()
a
b
False
>>> def c():
...     print 'c'
...     return True
... 
>>> print c() or a()
c
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Python's `or` operator short-circuits and it will be evaluated left to right:

```
if (foo > 5) or (bar > 6):
    print 'foobar'
```

If `foo > 5`, then `bar > 6` will not even be tested, as `True or <anything>` will be `True`. If `foo` isn't `> 5`, then `bar > 6` will be tested.

Answer (score 1):

Operator evaluated from left to right.
but only when the priority of all the operator is the same.
When the priority of the operators is not equal then
the operator will execute according to the priority.

ex.

> > False or False or True and False
> >     False
> >
> > True or False and True or False
> >     True
> >
> > False or False and True or False
> >     False

i.e  First in the expression the operator having the highest priority
executed then further execute.