# Evaluation of conditions around logical operator

Tags: python

Assuming evaluation happens left to right,

```
if (condition1 and condition2):
    .....
```

If condition1 returns False whether condition2 will be evaluated or not? Since, either `(False and True)` or `(False and False)` always going to be `False`.

Actually I have two questions,
1. Evaluation happens left to right or other way?
2. Whether all conditions will be evaluated in all scenarios?

For example,

```
if (5==6 and 100==200):
    pass
else:
    pass
```

`100==200` and `5==6` both will be evaluated or not?

Comment: right will be evaluated if left is true as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201362/in-which-order-is-an-if-statement-evaluated-in-python

Comment: @Slslam: Thanks for response