# Multiple 'In' operator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, in-operator

```
arr = [1, True, 'a', 2]
print('a' in arr in arr) # False
```

Can you explain me why this code will output 'False'?

**The question is closed.**

Answer from @KlausD.: Actually it is a comparison operator chaining and will be interpreted as `('a' in arr) and (arr in arr)`.

Comment: Just do `'a' in arr`

Comment: I believe you're expecting `True` because, you see `'a' in arr in arr` as `True in arr` ?

Comment: @Austin, just run this code. It output False.

Comment: Please explain waht your expected result was, and why. The question as it is, is unclear

Comment: @CIsForCookies, What did you not understand? I wanna understand why the expression " 'a' in arr in arr " is False

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753528/3890632) for info about operator chaining.

Answer (score 1):

It is `False` because `'a'` is `in 'arr'` but `'arr'` is not `in 'arr'`.

Meaning `'arr'` can't be in itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
arr = [1, True, 'a', 2]
print( 'a' in arr)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Or this:

```
arr = [1, True, 'a', 2]
print(bool(['a' in arr]) in arr)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: you can just do `print(('a' in arr) in arr)` instead of `print(bool(['a' in arr]) in arr)` but that does not check if `'a'` is in `arr`. It check if `True` is! Change arr to `arr = ['a', 2]` and verify

Comment: Question is not clear. I am assuming he wants to get the output from 'a' in arr as True and then check if True in arr.

Comment: Legit. I thought OP only wants to check if `'a' in arr`. Either way, what actually being checked is if `arr in arr`, and then if 'a' is in the result :-P

Comment: `bool(['a' in arr])` is almost certainly not any part of what the questioner wanted, considering it's calling `bool` on a one-element list, and it'll return `True` no matter whether or not `'a'` is in `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `print('a' in arr in arr) // False` is interpeted as `print('a' in arr in arr) // 0` which throws *ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero* error. If you meant to comment out the `False`, do it using `"#"`, not `"//"` (e.g. `print('a' in arr in arr) # False`)
2. <s>`'a' in arr in arr` is read from right to left<sup>[1]</sup>: check if `arr in arr` (False), and then check if `'a' in False` (False)</s>
3. *Using @Klaus D's helpful comment* - `print('a' in arr in arr)` is evaluated as `print(('a' in arr) and (arr in arr))` due to operator chaining. This, in turn is processed into `print(True and False)` -> `print(False)`

To check if `'a'` is in `arr`, just check `print('a' in arr)` # prints `True`

<s><sup>[1]  <sub>Well, not exactly. As can seen from [ [In which order is an if statement evaluated in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201362/in-which-order-is-an-if-statement-evaluated-in-python) ], the evaluation is right to left ,so this is what actually happens: (1) check if 'a' is in "something". (2) evaluate this "something" by checking if `arr in arr`. (3) use the reault of said something (which is `False` as sadly, `arr` isn't a member of itslef) and check if `'a'` is inside that (meaning, check if `'a' in True`, which again, is False[1]</sub></sup></s>

Comment: 1. Yeah, i'm sorry. There must be a "#"

Comment: 2. `'a' in False` is incorrect expression. It will throws error.

Comment: 1. Actually it is a comparison operator chaining and will be interpreted as `('a' in arr) and (arr in arr)`.

Comment: @KlausD, You're right. Thanks, man. It's correct answer for my question.