# switching sides of `and` statement in while loop boolean

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean, logical-operators

My problem is that I want to write a function `newlist`, that takes in a `list` of numbers as the parameter. It then returns a new list based on the parameter. The new list contains the same values of the original list up until it reaches the number 7.

my code that works:

```
def newlist(mylst):
    newlst = []
    idx = 0
    while (idx < len(mylst)) and (mylst[idx] != 7):
        newlst.append(mylst[idx])
        idx += 1
    return newlst
```

now when I switch the sides of the `and` statement like this:

`while (mylst[idx] != 7) and (idx < len(mylst)):`

it tells me that this is wrong and when passing a list as parameter, the index is
out of range. My question is why does it make a difference with what side of the `and` statement I start? I thought that the boolean is only True if both statements are True, regardless of order?

Comment: If your list has 10 numbers, and 5 is not one of them, the while loop will continue until your idx ==11, and one of your conditions `mylst[idx]` will be trying to find the 11th value of a 10 value list.

Comment: Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16201394/1079086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is due to the fact that the `and` operator uses short-circuiting.  This means that if the first operand is false, then the second operand is not evaluated.

In the following:

```
(idx < len(mylst)) and (mylst[idx] != 5)
```

The first operand is `(idx < len(mylst))`.  This checks whether `idx` is in range.  If it is, then the second operand, which uses `idx` as an index into `mylst`, is evaluated.  But if it isn't, then evaluation stops and the result of the expression is `False`.  In this way, it will never index out of bounds, because the first operand guards the evaluation of the second.

The second version is:

```
(mylst[idx] != 5) and (idx < len(mylst))
```

Here, the operands are reversed.  As a result, if `idx` is out of range, it will still try to use it as an index into `mylst`, causing an error.

So the two versions have a very significant difference.  The first version safely checks if `idx` is within range before attempting to use it as an index, while the second does not.