# Why does python chooses an empty list over empty dictionary and non-empty dictionary over non-empty list while using the "or" operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have been wondering about the use of *or* for choosing between two items if one has the probability of having the value of *None*, instead of using if else, (which I think is great btw)

Two examples:

```
None or [] -> returns []
None or {} -> returns {}
```

I've tried to use *or* in a scenario where one variable can be an empty dictionary and other can be an empty list. In this scenario the *or* returns the list but if the dictionary is non-empty, the dictionary is always chosen over the other variable. Results are the same i in both python 2.7.17 and python 3.6.9.

Examples:

```
{} or [] -> returns []
{1:2} or [2] -> returns {1:2}
```

Questions:

1. Is there a preference of an empty list over an empty dictionary?
2. Is there a preference of a non-empty dictionary over an non-empty list?
3. If there is no preference order, does any other rules/factors determines the outcome of this operation?

Thank you for your time and answers :) Have a good day.

Comment: The `or` operator returns the first truthy value from left to right.

Comment: Not exactly duplicate, but the answer can be found here, as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201362/in-which-order-is-an-if-statement-evaluated-in-python

Comment: `{} or []` returns `[]`, `[] or {}` returns `{}`. See the pattern?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) are the relevant docs

Comment: Great I missed that, thanks. {} or [] -> returns [] because since the empty dict is False and the or operator assumes that the second one is True?

Comment: No, see the duplicate link for a full explanation

Comment: It’s not that it “assumes it’s true”. If the first expression is falsey, it returns the second. If that’s *also* falsey, well, then the entire expression is falsey.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations :)

Comment: Yes. This is called short circuiting. Evaluation of Boolean expressions from left to right is stopped when it is clear that the expression is true. If the entire expression is false, it proceeds to the end before it returns the final false value. Empty data structures have a false value.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)